# Music notation: Left side dot

Tags: notation, sheet-music

What's the meaning of the highlighted left side dot?

I found it in the tango [Almagro by Vicente San Lorenzo](https://www.todotango.com/musica/tema/627/Almagro/) (lyrics by A. Timarni). It looks too clean to be noise in the score capture.

[image: left side dot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It's a printing error in the original.**

Similar dots appear

here

[image: Stray dot #1]

and here

[image: Stray dot #2]

and the dot is missing from this treble-staff fermata

[image: Missing dot]

**However**

There is a different copy of the score in a YouTube video, and it does not have any of those defects.

In particular, here's a screenshot of the measure where the left-side dot would otherwise appear.

[image: OP measure with no left-side dot]

Answer (score 3):

Just another copy of the score. It confirms that those dots are just "flyspecks" or something. (There's another tango called "Almagro" by Cipolla; they seem to have run out of names.)
https://www.todotango.com/english/music/song/627/Almagro/

Comment: The capacity to be able to sight-read 'flyspecks' is well revered in the music industry..!

Comment: Were you intending to link to a different copy of the score? The link provided is the same copy as the OP.

Comment: I didn't notice, I guess. I just linked to the sheet music associated with the performance. (There are other performances on that link, up a level.)

Comment: Almagro Is a neighborhood, so the name repetition isn't surprising.